# AggregateMessageDeliveryException

Tags: spring-integration

I'm trying to process I/O error while sending POST request via Http.outboundGateway, convert error message and send it onwards.
I can't intercept response and catch AggregateMessageDeliveryException.

```
     @Bean
IntegrationFlow defaultByteInFlow() {
    return f -> f
            .<byte[], ExchangeObject>transform(byteToExchangeObjectTransformer)
            .log(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO, "Sending data to recipient:", "headers.response_url + ' ' + @objectMapper.writeValueAsString(payload)")
            .handle(Jpa.updatingGateway(entityManagerFactory).entityClass(ExchangeObject.class).persistMode(PersistMode.PERSIST), e -> e.transactional(true))
            .<ExchangeObject, ExchangeObject>transform(e -> exchangeMapper.map(e))
            .handle(Http.<ExchangeObject>outboundChannelAdapter(p -> p.getHeaders().get(RESPONSE_URL_HEADER)));
}
```

App response (clipped) is:

> {
>       "timestamp": 1516892721965,
>       "status": 500,
>       "error": "Internal Server Error",
>       "exception": "org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AggregateMessageDeliveryException",
>       "message": "All attempts to deliver Message to MessageHandlers failed.; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: HTTP request execution failed for URI [http://localhost:8079/exchange/]; 
>       nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for \"http://localhost:8079/exchange/\": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: 
>       ...
>       "path": "/exchange"
>   }

Comment: `(clipped)` - can you show the whole thing? An `AggregateMessageDeliveryException` implies there are multiple subscribers on the channel.

Comment: Response: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HlVMAyjPhPgehXjp7Qn3nzEytsDTKBVe/view?usp=sharing

Application log: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G7QGQL2qtXDYD6Nrvg7rvDY5zAsqSP8k/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.handle()` has a second `Consumer<GenericEndpointSpec<H>>` argument where you can specify:

```
/**
 * Configure a list of {@link Advice} objects to be applied, in nested order, to the
 * endpoint's handler. The advice objects are applied only to the handler.
 * @param advice the advice chain.
 * @return the endpoint spec.
 */
public S advice(Advice... advice) {
```

One of which can be `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` with an appropriate option like:

```
/**
 * If true, the result of evaluating the onFailureExpression will
 * be returned as the result of AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(Message).
 *
 * @param returnFailureExpressionResult true to return the result of the evaluation.
 */
public void setReturnFailureExpressionResult(boolean returnFailureExpressionResult) {
```

The documentation is here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#expression-advice

Comment: Added 
`.handle(Http.<ExchangeObject>outboundChannelAdapter(p -> p.getHeaders().get(RESPONSE_URL_HEADER)),
                        c -> c.advice(expressionAdvice()))`

Comment: And 
`@Bean
    public Advice expressionAdvice() {
        ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
        advice.setSuccessChannelName("success.input");
        advice.setOnSuccessExpressionString("payload + ' was successful'");
        advice.setFailureChannelName("failure.input");
        advice.setOnFailureExpressionString(
                "payload + ' was bad, with reason: ' + #exception.cause.message");
        advice.setTrapException(true);
        return advice;
    }`
fixes the problem

Comment: While `advice.setReturnFailureExpressionResult(true\false);`
 has no effect at all